# Modal dialog goes in the background after some time

Tags: wpf

I have problem in showing modal dialog in WPF. and below is my code

```
public class MyDialog : Window
{
}
```

**Test.cs**

```
    var mydialog = new MyDialog();
    mydialog.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    mydialog.ShowDialog();
```

when below code executes it opens up the window and it stays on top of the application but after few seconds window goes in the background. is there any other way to handle this apart from using Topmost = true.

Comment: Doesnt happen on my system.

Comment: I have a dual monitor setup and happens consistently.